# Auto populate select boxes at page load from array's via using jQuery/Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So i'm trying to fill three select boxes at the same time, when page load. The data for boxes is from array's. So one box for $cpuArr, one box for $motherboardsArr and one box for $videocardArr.

**PHP**

```
$cpuArr = file_get_contents('data/cpu.json');
$motherboardsArr = file_get_contents('data/motherboard.json');
$videocardArr = file_get_contents('data/video-card.json');

if(isset($_POST['request']) == 1){

    echo $cpuArr;// Sending response
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Ajax request
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'logic.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {request: 1},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function fetchItems(response){

            for( var i = 0; i< response.length; i++){
                $('#cpu').append("<option value='"+response[i]['ID']+"'>"+response[i]['Name']+"</option>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
                            <select id='cpu'>
                                <option value="0">-Select CPU-</option>
                            </select>
                            <select id='motherboard'>
                                <option value="">-Select motherboard-</option>
                            </select>
                            <select id='video-card'>
                                <option value="">-Select Video Card-</option>
                            </select>
```

Its working only for one, i dont know how to make it with three boxes, without repating the code.I will be grateful if anyone can help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all data inside `associative array` and then use  `json_encode` i.e :

```
  if(isset($_POST['request']) == 1){
        $data = array("cpuArr"=>$cpuArr, 
                      "motherboardsArr"=>$motherboardsArr,  
                       "videocardArr"=>$videocardArr);
         echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Then , inside your success function of ajax you can access them like below :

```
success: function fetchItems(response){
      var cpu = response.cpuArr;
      var mb = response.motherboardsArr;
      var vdio = response.videocardArr;

            for( var i = 0; i< cpu.length; i++){
                $('#cpu').append("<option value='"+cpu[i]['ID']+"'>"+cpu[i]['Name']+"</option>");
            }
      //same for others ...
   }
```

Comment: Still not working dude, i make the other three for's but nothing is loading in select boxes. I see the response with array in console, but nothing from success function of ajax.

Comment: WIll need to either parse each property value or json_decode() it server side

Comment: Array
(
    [cpuArr] => [
    {
        "ID": "001",
        "Name": "Intel1" 
        },
    ............    
]
    [motherboardsArr] => [
    {
        "ID": "001",
        "Name": "Motherboard1" 
        },
    {
       .............
]
    [videocardArr] => [
    {
        "ID": "001",
        "Name": "Nvidia1" 
        },
    {
       .............
]
)

Comment: Yes its working now with json_decode() Thanks Swati and Charlietfl Have a nice day ! :)

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for pointing that out . I completely forgot about that :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one request and just make a GET request with `$.getJSON()`

PHP

```
function getFileAsArray($type){
   $path = "data/".$type.".json";
   return json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
}

$types = ['cpu','motherboard','video-card'];

foreach($types as $type){
   $output[$type] = getFileAsArray($type);
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

JQuery:

```
$.getJSON('logic.php').then(data => {    
      $.each(data, (key, arr)=>{
         const options = arr.map(o => new Option(o.Name, o.ID));
         // keys in php matching ids in html
         $('select#' + key).append(options);
      });
});
```